# WSO2 Scim2 Password Change

Tags: wso2, scim2, wso2-identity-server

I am currently using IS 5.5.0 and utilizing the SCIM2 API to provision users that will eventually need their passwords changed. I have successfully created the users  using the POST operation and can update certain attributes using the PATCH operation. My question is, can I update the user's password using the PATCH operation using the scim2/Users/(.*) endpoint? I've been unsuccessful so far. Here is a sample request: 
`PATCH https://myhostname:9443/scim2/Users/f7853b65-e4e8-47b0-a000-e113f95cda63 HTTP/1.1`
 With a request body of: 
`{
     "schemas":
       ["urn:ietf:params:scim:api:messages:2.0:PatchOp"],
     "Operations":[{
        "op":"replace",
        "path":"password",
        "value":"asdf"
     }]
   }`
I haven't been able to find any documentation leading a definitive answer so any feedback would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
curl -v -k 
    --user admin:admin 
    -X PATCH 
    -d '{"password":"test123"}' 
    --header "Content-Type:application/json" 
    https://localhost:9443/wso2/scim/Users/f7853b65-e4e8-47b0-a000-e113f95cda63
```

Answer (score 1):

There was a known issue when updating password field using SCIM2 APIs in IS 5.5.0 (via PUT/PATCH). Please refer [1] for more information on this. However this was fixed in IS 5.6.0. Can you please try the same with IS 5.6.0?

[1] https://github.com/wso2/product-is/issues/3009